# How to call WEB API with a list of data for delete method

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to make a delete WEB API call through angular $http, and i want to send a list of Ids to my API method.

Here is my angular call.

```
function deleteItem(id) {
            return $http({ url: delete_Url, data: {itemIds:[id]}, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, method: "DELETE" });
        }
```

WebAPI

```
[Route("/product/items")]
        [HttpDelete]
        public HttpResponseMessage RemoveItems( List<Guid> itemIds)
        {
            .....
        }
```

Problem is I'm getting nothing into my **itemIds List**

thanks

Comment: have you inspected the actual request in browser dev tools to see what is actually sent and it is what you expect?

Comment: if `id` is already an array when it gets passed to your method, you don't need the square brackets around it in the $http call

Comment: @chriszumberge id is  a Guid I'm converting it into Array.

Comment: @charlietfl I have observed it on fiddler it is set to : Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*

Comment: doesn't isolate if correct data is sent though